# Parse Issue error in the code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

There is a syntax error in the following code:

```
[videoView loadHTMLString:videoHTML baseURL:nil];
```

statement of this code but i m unable to get it.

```
- (void)embedYouTube {

    videoHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
             <html>\
             <head>\
             <style type=\"text/css\">\
             iframe {position:absolute; top:50%%; margin-top:-130px;}\
             body {background-color:#000; margin:0;}\
             </style>\
             </head>\
             <body>\
            <iframe width=\"560%%\" height=\"315px\" src="http://youtube.com/embed/-0Xa4bHcJu8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>\
             </body>\
             </html>", videoURL];

             [videoView loadHTMLString:videoHTML baseURL:nil];

}
```

Comment: The difference in syntax markup around `src="http` doesn't look familiar? Perhaps your code is missing something there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes around the URL and the frameborder:

```
src=\"http://...
```

Comment: fixed that but now getting message for this statement  </html>", videoURL]; Message is Data argument not used by format string.

Comment: @user1452248 yes, because you don't reference it at all in the format string - what are you trying to use it for?

Comment: So in place of videoURL i need to give the actual address of youtubevideo

Comment: @user1452248 then use `... src=\"%@\"", videoURL];` - but frankly, didn't you take any time to have a look at NSString's documentation?