# Unable to load html string in UIWebView using loadHTMLString:baseURL in iOS?

Tags: html, iphone, ios, uiwebview

I am trying to embed youtube video into my iOS application.For that I have created a `UIWebView`  & trying to load the `Youtube` video from following [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974060/parse-issue-error-in-the-code)

I have gone through the all the answers for the above problem. Even then its not working. 
I have also tried loading very simple HTML

```
 NSString *embedHTML =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body>Hello World</body></html>"];
 [webView loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:nil];
```

Even then, I am getting compile error `Parse Issue Expecte ']'`

I have tried cleaning, quitting the XCode & relaunching it again. I donno, I am not able to use that method. How to use the above `loadHTMLString` method for my `UIWebView`.

***PS : Please do not tag this question as duplicate. I have tried all the solutions in `Stackoverflow`. Nothing has worked***

Comment: did everything except debugging? log the frame of webview and please add  it here

Comment: @LithuT.V.. I am not even able to compile the code. Its a compile time error.

Comment: commenting which line compiles the code?

Comment: Commenting `[webView loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:nil];
 ` line compiles the code perfectly

Comment: I am getting same error.. how you solved it?

Comment: @ChitraKhatri.. My problem was not yet solved.

Answer (score 5):

```
WebView *webDesc = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 50, 276, 228)];

NSString *embedHTML = @"<html><head></head><body><p>1. You agree that you will be the technician servicing this work order?.<br>2. You are comfortable with the scope of work on this work order?.<br>3. You understand that if you go to site and fail to do quality repair for  any reason, you will not be paid?.<br>4. You must dress business casual when going on the work order.</p></body></html>";

webDesc.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
webDesc.opaque = NO;
webDesc.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[webDesc loadHTMLString: embedHTML baseURL: nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (NSString *)getHTMLContent
{
    NSString *cssPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"baseline" ofType:@"css"];

    NSData *cssData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:cssPath];
    NSString *cssStyle = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:cssData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

    NSString *subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ | %@", self.article.author, [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.article.publishedDate]];

    NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;'></head><style type=\"text/css\">%@</style><body><div id=\"container\"><h1>%@</h1><p class='subtitle'>%@</p>%@</div></body></html>", cssStyle, self.article.title, subtitle, self.article.content];

    return htmlString;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple. You just have to add only one line. Try It:

```
NSString *htmlString = @"<html><head></head><body><p>1. You agree that you will be the technician servicing this work order?.<br>2. You are comfortable with the scope of work on this work order?.<br>3. You understand that if you go to site and fail to do quality repair for  any reason, you will not be paid?.<br>4. You must dress business casual when going on the work order.</p></body></html>";
[WebView loadHTMLString: htmlString baseURL: nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to provide more code if you want people to help you. I just used webView in a similar way and it's working fine.

```
self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];
self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
[self.webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

//pass the string to the webview
[self.webView loadHTMLString:[[self.itineraryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"body"] baseURL:nil];

//add it to the subview
[self.view addSubview:self.webView];
```

Can you provide more information and code?

Comment: This is what I did
`UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];
 NSString *embedHTML =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body>Hello World</body></html>"];
 [webView loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:nil];
`
Thats it, this is what I did. I am getting compile time error. That `loadHTMLString` method itself is not working. Even though everything is right, it showing `Parse Issue Expecte ']'` as compile error

Comment: Are you sure the error is from the webView? If you comment out the webView lines, the error disappear? Are you adding the webview to the main view?

Comment: Yes. Problem is with webview. If I comment that line, then everything is working fine. Even before adding itself I am getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

it doesnt seems like an issue on webview.Please do add the code where it breaks.Error says you missed a `]` somewhere in the code

Comment: @LithuT.V.. No, not because I left `]`. I have even created a new project & there I have written the same line. I dint even copy paste it. I have typed manually everything. Even then same error in other project too :-(

Comment: which line you are talking about ??

Comment: webview frame please?also check webview has valid memory.connected properly .code seems ok to me

Answer (score -2):

try to load the url directly into the webview :

```
 UIWebView *webview=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 250)];

[webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://youtube.com/embed/-0Xa4bHcJu8"]]];
```

Comment: Answer does not related with question